# vqmod not reading from cache

Tags: opencart, vqmod

I got a strange situation.
I'm using VQMOD with Opencart and everything worked alright until I uploaded all the code to a secure ssl hosting.

VQMOD still works and is making all the cache files in vqcache. In checked.cache file however not all the modded files are listed. Is this normal?

logs, vqcache, checked.cache, mods.cache, system/cache and logs have permissions set to 777

It seems that VQMOD is not using all the plugins (using the normal files instead of the vqcache file). I have no errors.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Checklist of things you need to do

- Delete the files `/vqmod/mods.cache` and `/vqmod/checked.cache`
- Remove all cache files from the `/vqmod/vqcache/` directory
- Make sure your write permissions are valid on `/vqmod/`, `/vqmod/vqcache/` and `/vqmod/logs/`
- Make sure the files in `/vqmod/xml/` are readable by the web server user
- Make sure the file `/vqmod/xml/vqmod_opencart.xml` is present
- Go to `http://yoursite.com/vqmod/install/` to make sure everything is installed correctly

Comment: Did all of that. I found out that when /vqmod/mods.cache and /vqmod/checked.cache are newer (or older, dont remember) than the /vqmod/vqcache/ no modding will take place. "} elseif(file_exists($modCache) && filemtime($modCache) >= self::$_lastModifiedTime) {" around line 241. I recreated all the folder in vqmod and it suddenly worked again.

Comment: @Meddie Changing those round will make it re-generate cache files at the wrong time. It's set correctly. It sounds like your vqcache folder retained the time from your current system instead of the new system (or vice versa). Simply deleting all of the files should fix that, though the vqcache folder itself may have needed re-creating to make sure it had the correct file time